Upon publish of item with SPS, every time different version of item is getting displayed on site
On the higher environment, I published 3 versions of items with the SPS. But on the website, different versions are displayed each time the page is refreshed. Sometimes 3rd latest version, sometimes 2nd and sometimes 1st version.
This issue is reproducible for a sometime only, after a few hours issue is not reproducible.
What can be the reason for this behaviour?

Do you have multiple CD instances? If yes, do you have the file Sitecore.Publishing.Service.Delivery.config on all the CD instances?

Can you check on all the CD server following patch is added to clear cache..publishingservice:cache:clear. This patch is defined inside the Sitecore.Publishing.Service.Delivery.config file...
